# Platform device recognition

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

How does any device when connected to port(say serial port) of the development board registers itself(struct platform_device *pdev) to the driver?

The driver then registers pdev to the kernel using platform_driver_register()function. Am I right?

Platform devices are the devices which is directly connected to CPU without any Bus.
Then how do we come to know, that which device requires bus and which donot?

Comment: *"How does any device ... registers itself ... to the driver?"* -- HW devices don't do any "registering". A device driver would **probe** for the existence of the HW it supports, or will be installed when the HW is detected (e.g. self-identifying USB devices) or configured in (e.g. Device Tree). The (SW) driver will **register** itself with an I/O subsystem or a platform driver, and register instances of HW that it probed. *"connected to CPU without any Bus"* -- There is still a bus. Find a block diagram for any (digital) computer or SoC, and there will be (at least) a CPU bus.

Comment: @sawdust:Suppose I have two UART's connected, ie one(UART1) is used with teraterm (console) and the 2nd one(UART4 connected in expansion slot of my development board) which one will my driver register/how do I register the UART4 because UART1 is already working?

Comment: *"I have two UART's connected..."* -- To what, to each other?  UARTs are peripherals.  They have to be attached to a processor. What/which/how_many processors are involved in this scenario?  On which CPU is *"my driver"* executing?  What/which device(s) is(/are) *"my driver"* servicing?  What is *"my development board"*?  What is an *"expansion slot"*?  What does *"UART1 is already working?"* mean?  (Please do not try to explain in a short comment, but rather append to your question a complete response.)

Comment: @sawdust: I am using omap4460 pandaboard which is loaded with linux OS.Expansion slot in the board is multiplexed/configured to connect to uart4 instance.UART1 instance is connected to my PC through serial port and I am using it for the console operation.Now how is the uart4 instance registered?

Comment: OMAP4460 has 4 integrated UARTs.  What you call an *"Expansion slot"* for UART4 is merely an extension of the SoC pinouts on the Pandaboard. The Linux UART device driver **omap-serial** would be installed (i.e. its **init()** routine is executed) one time as a platform driver, but each instance of a UART node specified in the Device Tree would cause the **probe()** routine to be executed.  In your scenario two instantiations of UARTs (aka **ports**) would be installed.  The device driver is reentrant, and can support more than one instance of UARTs.

Comment: @sawdust: Thanks for your time.I am writing a simple driver for UART4 communication.Do I have to disable the uart4 instance in Device Tree?. How is DEVICE TREE mapped to probe() routine? .And how to register UART4 instance in my driver code?

Comment: *"Do I have to disable the uart4 instance in Device Tree?"* -- If you did that, then no device driver at all would be installed, and you would not be able to use UART4.  You would have to modify the DT to specify a different device driver, your driver, for UART4, which is the `compatible = "ti,omap4-uart";` line

Comment: @sawdust:Do I have to modify/add new uart in the DT which is in arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi file? (uart4: serial@4806e000 {compatible = "ti,omap4-uart";ti,hwmods = "uart4";clock-frequency = <48000000>;"What exactly in this?").Now in my driver code 9           #if defined(CONFIG_OF)
 static const struct of_device_id omap_serial_of_match[] = {
         { .compatible = "ti,omap4-uart" },
         {},};
 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, omap_serial_of_match);
 #endif

Comment: Already answered in my previous comment: **You would have to modify the DT to specify a *different* device driver.**